# JSON plugin for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, json

I was googling for hours but could not find a useful JSON plugin for Eclipse.

I am trying to have something like the following:

[image]
<sub>(source: [developerlife.com](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/jObj_Visual_thumb2.png))</sub>

Does anybody knows such a plugin?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's an [Eclipse JSON Editor Plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipsejsonedit/) on SourceForge. Its Outline view might be something like what you want. (I haven't actually used it myself.)

Comment: thanks but i think this plugin isn't available anybore. the link and the achive file is broken

Comment: I was able to download it without any problems. Have you tried installing it through Eclipse's built-in update system?

Comment: To install the JSON Editor, follow [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5482776/175679) - using the dropins directory

Comment: Update site is (Json Editor Plugin with spaces NOT %20 !) [http:// eclipsejsonedit.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/eclipsejsonedit/trunk/Json Editor Plugin] Also you must untick "Group items by category" to see it as per [their forum topic](http://sourceforge.net/p/eclipsejsonedit/discussion/957258/thread/bc439e53/)

Comment: Update site moved to https://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipsejsonedit/files/update/

Comment: You can also get it on the Eclipse Marketplace. It works, but is a bit clunky. Right click > Format Text to autoformat (you can bind this manually).

Comment: Sadly, this plugin is not working with big JSON files (Eclipse freezes, see https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=487906). Still looking for one that can handle files of a few MB.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend using [JSON Tools](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/json-tools), it is easy to install and actively maintained.

Comment: it seems promising, but there is no Help and no Support channel that I can find.  I'm trying to turn off Validation and it doesn't seem to be in the preferences.

Comment: In the Outline Window I see no text in Eclipse Mars.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need a eclipse plugin to edit json files, you can use this:

http://jsoneditor.appspot.com/

or this:

http://jsoneditoronline.org/

Comment: Good questions are not only useful for the OP, but also for others that have the same question. So how do you know that I don't need an eclipse plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the aptana JSON editor with outline view quite helpful. Click 
[here](http://www.aptana.com/downloads/start)

Comment: The link is broken.