# How to convert jar file to eclipse project

Tags: jar

I want to convert my jar file to eclipse project, so that i can make changes in the existing code. Can anyone help me with this. I tried extracting jar using jar xf myjar.jar command through command prompt but it gave me only .class files and i want to generate .java files of my project through it.

Comment: the answer you're looking for can be found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917802/how-to-open-a-jar-file-in-eclipse here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to open a jar file in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917802/how-to-open-a-jar-file-in-eclipse)