# Offine installation of PMD plugin for Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pmd

I am trying to download and install PMD plugin for Eclipse offline but did not succeed in doing so.

I downloaded following 2 zips:

- net.sourceforge.pmd.eclipse-3.2.6.v200903300643.zip (this version matches with the one which I installed online)
- pmd-eclipse-1.8.0

Not sure which one to use and how to configure it in Eclipse.

I searched a lot but did not find proper steps for the offine installation and configuration.

Comment: Below link will help someone. Please refer below link. Mr.Konstantin Komissarchik answer helped to me.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482554/how-to-install-plugin-for-eclipse-from-zip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case it contains site archieve:

Goto Help->Install New Software

Click Add...

In the Add Repository Dialog click Archive and point to your zip. Rest of the installation is as you would do with an online installation.

Else:

Extract the zip
Copy all plugins to your target eclipse plugins folder

Copy all features to your target eclipse features folder

launch eclipse with -clean option

Comment: Thanks For the Reply,
But since the archieve does not contain artifect file we cannot add it directly. I got the offline work around steps but did not succed in doing so.what i am looking is the exacts steps to make it work.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the latest 4.0 version of the plugin by pointing your Eclipse installer here:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/pmd/files/pmd-eclipse/update-site/