# ws4e (java webstart) plugin installation in aptana studio 3/eclipse indigo

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pydev

I have installed Aptana Studio 3 (3.2.2) on linux (mint linux). Aptana Studio 3 is just eclipse Indigo (3.7.2) with some extra plugins and stuff added if I understand correctly.

I downloaded the ws4e (java webstart) plugin for eclipse manually from http://webstart.sourceforge.net/ and unzipped it to the aptana/eclipse installation directory, so there is a folder Aptana_Studio_3/plugins/net.sourceforge.webstart_1.2.1/ with a webstart.jar in it and other stuff (alongside other plugins installed from aptana+eclipse repositories). But somehow this plugin doesn't get picked up by aptana studio after a restart. The plugin isn't listed with the installed plugins, and it's functionality is also not available.

I have no clue how to debug this problem, or what is going wrong.

Just in case it is useful: this is my java version:

java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode)

Comment: Please check the solution at 


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482554/how-to-install-plugin-for-eclipse-from-zip

Comment: Did you manage to get it working?