# How to update/add specific library in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am using xtext library version 2.3.1, and I want to be able to use class ArrayLiterals.
Based on javadocs [here](http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/xtext/javadoc/2.4/org/eclipse/xtext/xbase/lib/ArrayLiterals.html#ArrayLiterals%28%29), its available from 2.4.

How can I update/add the ArrayLiterals only?

I tried updating the whole eclipse, and I am getting errors on deprecated functions like shiftleft for the primitive types.

Comment: Did you try installing the plug-in manually. A quick How-to for this is present at this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482554/how-to-install-plugin-for-eclipse-from-zip

Answer (score 2):

You can follow instruction in the following link, it not only just helps you update `xtext Library` but also other libraries too.

**Here is the link [Ref Link](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.xtext.doc/contents/005-installation.html)**

**Install Pre-Configured Eclipse With Xtext**

- Go to http://xtext.itemis.com and select the distribution that matches your OS.
- Unzip the archive into the directory of your choice. Windows Users should choose a directory close to the root since the zip contains a deeply nested folder structure. The maximum path length on windows may not exceed roughly 256 characters.
- Launch Eclipse and select the workspace location. It is basically the location for your user data and project files and may be an empty directory.

**Install Xtext From Update Site**

If you have no existing Eclipse installed, it is probably easier to choose a pre-configured Eclipse. Alternatively, you can go to http://www.eclipse.org and choose the Eclipse IDE for Java Developers. Find the download link that matches your platform and follow the installation instructions above to extract and launch Eclipse.

- Choose Help -> Install New Software... from the menu bar and Add... the following update site: http://download.itemis.de/updates/. This site aggregates all the necessary and optional components of Xtext.
- Select the Xtext SDK from the TMF Xtext category and hit Next until you can Finish the wizard.
- After a quick download and a restart of Eclipse, Xtext is ready to use.

IF you are planning to use first method, here is the [Download Link](http://xtext.itemis.com/xtext/language=en/36553/downloads) to get Xtext 2.4 or later version.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot update just a tiny part of xtext. Eclipse plugins declare their dependencies to other plugins by version numbers and Eclipse makes sure that you don't break that contract. So you always have to upgrade at least a whole Eclipse feature.

To do so, open Help -> About Eclipse -> Installation Details. Expand the tree to find your xtext features, then select the "Update" button to update that single feature. The update manager will check the dependencies and may add additional dependent components to the update, which you need to upgrade as well.

If you don't find any updates that way, go to Help -> Install new software and add the Itemis update site http://download.itemis.de/updates/ (or any other update site you know hosting the wanted version). Then repeat the above procedure.