# GAE SDK 1.9.4 breaks GPE 3.5.1

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-eclipse-plugin

When i tried to generate the client library using eclipse interface i got this erro:

[image]

> eclipse.buildId=M20120914-1800 java.version=1.7.0_25
>   java.vendor=Oracle Corporation BootLoader constants: OS=macosx,
>   ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=pt_BR Framework arguments:  -product
>   org.eclipse.epp.package.dsl.product -keyring
>   /Users/renanfranca/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation Command-line
>   arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -product
>   org.eclipse.epp.package.dsl.product -keyring
>   /Users/renanfranca/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation Error Thu May 01
>   19:39:22 BRT 2014 Unexpected Exception
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.GenerateSwarmApiAction$1.run(GenerateSwarmApiAction.java:82)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.google.api.server.spi.tools.ClientLibGenerator$Language   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     at
>   com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmApiCreator.createClientLibFromApiConfig(SwarmApiCreator.java:113)
>     at
>   com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmApiCreator.createSwarmApi(SwarmApiCreator.java:258)
>     at
>   com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmServiceCreator.create(SwarmServiceCreator.java:444)
>     at
>   com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.GenerateSwarmApiAction$1.run(GenerateSwarmApiAction.java:80)
>     ... 1 more

I tried the command line at the root of the project:

> $SDK/endpoints.sh get-client-lib my.package.MyEndpointsApi

And its only generated the endpoints client libs, but not the folder:

> myendpointsapi-v1-generated-source

When i got back to appengine 1.9.3 it's work like a charm again..

Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: It seems that something is wrong with 1.9.4. I have got various other reports from users following my tutorials on Google Cloud Endpoints that 1.9.4 code generation seems broken but works well with 1.9.3. It is better to stick with 1.9.3 for now.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10871

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/google-plugin-for-eclipse/issues/detail?id=278

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received this email today..

> Updates:
>           Status: Fixed
>           Labels: Release-3.6.0
>
> Comment #7 on issue 278 by rdayal@google.com: GPE 3.5.1 incompatible
>   with GAE SDK 1.9.4 - Endpoint generation fails
>   http://code.google.com/p/google-plugin-for-eclipse/issues/detail?id=278

**I hope a GPE update will come son** (I CAN'T WAIT)

**I gave up from Eclipse**
I'm using AndroidStudio now and it's generate the libraries automatically: http://rominirani.com/2014/08/27/gradle-tutorial-part-10-consuming-endpoints-in-android-code/

Start AndroidStudio from this awesome post Series:
http://rominirani.com/2014/07/28/gradle-tutorial-series-an-overview/

Answer (score 5):

In line with Romin, I also think that the AppEngine SDK 1.9.4 breaks GPE 3.5.1. I had the same problem when I updated to SDK 1.9.4 a few days ago. I rolled back to 1.9.3, and the endpoints are generated successfully. I reported GPE issue no. [278](https://code.google.com/p/google-plugin-for-eclipse/issues/detail?id=278).

Comment: Can you post the issue number so we can star it?

Answer (score 2):

**For those who need manual installation instructions of GAE SDK 1.9.3 on Eclipse**

I had the same issue and found this download link to the GAE SDK 1.9.3 
https://storage.googleapis.com/appengine-sdks/featured/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.3.zip

**How to manually install GAE SDK 1.9.3  in eclipse?** 
Since I am very new to Android, I took some time to learn to manually install an eclipse plugin. Please read Konstantin's answer [how-to-install-plugin-for-eclipse-from-zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482554/how-to-install-plugin-for-eclipse-from-zip)

Comment: Sorry, how you installed the 1.9.3 version? I tried putting the unzipped folder in the eclipse/dropins but doesn't work, and in the zip there isn't the plugin folder. I hope you can explain me the steps to install this SDK, thank you very much.

Comment: Didn't work for me either. After adding SDK 1.9.3 in the dropins folder, when I restarted Eclipse and located the SDK in the local resources for updates, Eclipse reported that it was not a valid repository

Answer (score 2):

For those how hasn't the SDK 1.9.3 as me, is possibile to install this SDK following the next steps:

1. Download the SDK from here: 
   https://storage.googleapis.com/appengine-sdks/featured/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.3.zip
2. Unzip in the folder Eclipse/plugins/
3. Reboot Eclipse and go to Properties -> Google -> App Engine
4. Click on Configure SDKs
5. Click on Add
6. Browse to the folder where you unziped the plugin and click Ok.
7. Choose now the new SDK 1.9.3. That's all ;)

Answer (score 2):

I used this link to obtain the 1.9.3 sdk:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.appengine/appengine-java-sdk/1.9.3

other then that, yeah, just add via the Configure SDK properties

Answer (score 1):

My experience was exactly the same: I couldnt generate Cloud EndPoint Libraries and the datastore didn´t work via Android.

If you want to downgrade your Google App Engine SDK after you updated it, seek into your **Eclipse installation folder** and look for the old SDK in plugings folder.

Afterwards you can import these old SDK to your projects from "Project Properties" and "Google/App Engine", "Configure SDK", "Add". There, you must fin the path I talked about.

Now you can chose both SDK.

I tried with **1.9.3** and it worked again.

**Edited**: Finally this soulution didn´t work, so I downgrade to my last stable version of Google App Engine SDK, the 1.9.2. This one worked for me.

Comment: Could you please explain what is the best way to downgrade the AppEngine SDK version?