# Error while generating client library in google app engine sdk - 1.9.6

Tags: android, google-app-engine, gae-eclipse-plugin, maven-gae-plugin

I have update my eclipse app engine plugin version to 1.9.6 and its creating problem for me. Whenever i try to `Generate Cloud endpoint client library` at that time its throwing exception and library is not generated. I searched on this issue but no success. If anypne have solved this issue then please help me to get over this problem. 
Thank you.

Error Stack:

```
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.GenerateSwarmApiAction$1.run(GenerateSwarmApiAction.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.server.spi.tools.ClientLibGenerator$Language
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmApiCreator.createClientLibFromApiConfig(SwarmApiCreator.java:113)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmApiCreator.createSwarmApi(SwarmApiCreator.java:258)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmServiceCreator.create(SwarmServiceCreator.java:444)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.GenerateSwarmApiAction$1.run(GenerateSwarmApiAction.java:80)
    ... 1 more
Root exception:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.server.spi.tools.ClientLibGenerator$Language
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmApiCreator.createClientLibFromApiConfig(SwarmApiCreator.java:113)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmApiCreator.createSwarmApi(SwarmApiCreator.java:258)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmServiceCreator.create(SwarmServiceCreator.java:444)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.GenerateSwarmApiAction$1.run(GenerateSwarmApiAction.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I and others are having the same problem.  It seems that GPE 3.5.1 is not compatible with AppEngine SDK>1.9.3, so I have moved back to 1.9.3 and I can now generate endpoints again.

Please go to https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10871 and "star" the issue so that Google fixes it.

In the meantime, I recommend you move back to AppEngine 1.9.3 using these instructions: [GAE SDK 1.9.4 breaks GPE 3.5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23418169/gae-sdk-1-9-4-breaks-gpe-3-5-1)

Comment: yes, i have already moved my app engine application to 1.9.3 and its working fine. i have also reported same bug on your link.