# eclipse commandline to install plugin from remote zip

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, p2

Hi All trying to install eclipse plugin from remote site using chef. Remote site has zip file which is accessible as url. I understand how to do it from local zip file. But this case is q mix of url and zip.

Please see the following syntax that I am using

```
eclipse\\eclipse \
-application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director \
-noSplash \
-repository \ http://nikiclvm4.xxx.yyyy.com:8081/artifactory/simple/tools-local/chef_bin/ccollab_client_8_3_8301_001_update_site.zip \
-installIUs \
com.smartbear.collaborator.base.feature.feature.group,\
com.smartbear.collaborator.8.3.8301.001
```

From local drive I used following syntax which worked

-repository jar:file:/C:/Users/xxxx/Downloads/ccollab_client_8_3_8301_001_update_site.zip!/ \

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: I have used workaround of downloading it first and then install from local drive. I was curious to know if there is a way I can do this directly.

Answer (score 1):

Use as repository url the following mind the ending ! and slash (and make sure that proxy settings are properly configured)

```
jar:http://nikiclvm4.xxx.yyyy.com:8081/artifactory/simple/tools-local/chef_bin/ccollab_client_8_3_8301_001_update_site.zip!/
```

drawback is that p2 is downloading the whole zip file first and then accessing the contained repo afterwards.