# Android Development Tool 23.0.0 and Android L Update error in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, android-sdk-2.3, android-5.0-lollipop

I updated my SDK with latest release of `Android L` and restarted my eclipse i.e running on `ADT V.22`. But when I Check for update from 
`Hep -> Check for updates`, it says `No updates were found`.

I manually tried to download ADT bundle from official [website](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html#Download)  and tried to install `ADT-23.0.0.zip` from `Help -> Install New Software`  and described installation guide over site, but it gave me error

```
 Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Android Development Tools 23.0.0.1245622 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.feature.group 23.0.0.1245622)
  Software currently installed: Google App Engine Tools for Android 3.5.1.v201312301719-rel-r42 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.mobile.android.feature.feature.group 3.5.1.v201312301719-rel-r42)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    ADT XML Overlay 22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206 (overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay 22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206)
    ADT XML Overlay 23.0.0.1245622 (overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay 23.0.0.1245622)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Development Tools 23.0.0.1245622 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.feature.group 23.0.0.1245622)
    To: overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay [23.0.0.1245622]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Development Tools 22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206)
    To: overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay [22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Google App Engine Tools for Android 3.5.1.v201312301719-rel-r42 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.mobile.android.feature.feature.group 3.5.1.v201312301719-rel-r42)
    To: com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 22.0.0
```

And it also giving me error while I compile my exiting project that were running perfectly before update. Error  is:

```
[2014-06-27 12:03:01 - my App] The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured.
[2014-06-27 12:03:01 -my App] You must restart adb and Eclipse.
[2014-06-27 12:03:01 - my App] Please ensure that adb is correctly located at 'E:\Android-sdk\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130522\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' and can be executed.
```

I tired various solution provided earlier for killing adb server and restarting again using `adb kill-server` command.

Can anyone resolve or guide me how to build and compile my existing projects with this new SDK update in eclipse.

Comment: Check out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437564/update-eclipse-with-android-development-tools-23/24448709#24448709)  it will helps you by following this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437564/update-eclipse-with-android-development-tools-23/24448709#24448709)

Comment: No I already tried that but it's not working even

Comment: I had the same problem. I tried to import a new project but it never imports!

Comment: @HimanshuAgarwal can you tell?

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem and just solved it.  what I did is **uninstall entirely the android plugin from eclipse** (from the "about" section..) including trace view..

Do **not** restart eclipse at this point!

then added again the ADT Plugin (https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/)

the problem solved!

I guess it's a bug with the SDK manager or ADT Plugin update mechanism..

Comment: Don't restart eclipse after uninstalling, for me it gave error *eclipse cant be opened 10810*, Just after uninstalling the old one, install latest plugin and everything will work fine!

Comment: Great, I just made that mistake... now reinstalling this thing again, which by far has earned on my list the award for greatest failure of all IDEs.

Comment: I also did the same thing: uninstall the adt plugin from eclipse from about section and then re-install it.It will surely work.

Comment: @waqas716 I did the same mistake of restarting eclipse and it's showing 10810 error. What should I do now?

Comment: @StarWars Fortunately I had a backup of eclipse before doing it. Nothing worked except using the old backup. And for testing Android L I used Android Studio then, let me know too if you get it to work.

Comment: unfortunately this method now results in eclipse.exe getting deleted when you quit eclipse. you can remove the old adt plugin stuff and without restarting eclipse install the new but when you quite eclipse the eclipse.exe is gone anyways. bummer. trying for reinstalling adt now..

Comment: It will still fail. My eclipse stopped working

Answer (score 6):

It saves my day...!

If for some reason you installed an ADT preview and need to **revert back** to the current stable, you can't use the dialog to install "new" software since what you want is actually an older one. Instead do this:

- Open Help > About Eclipse... on Windows or Linux. On Mac, use the
  app's menu > About...
- Click the "Installation Details" button.
- Select the "Installation History" tab.
- Select one of the previous configurations.
- Click the "Revert" button at the bottom.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am depending on this article 
[How to install plugin for Eclipse from .zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482554/how-to-install-plugin-for-eclipse-from-zip)
and I made it sorta work. still needs some fix from me. I'll update soon.

This is based on the idea of opening the ADT plugin zip file and copy it's contents by hand , an old fashioned copy-paste method. I still could not yet make it well configured, but the tools do work.

*Don't forget to uninstall older ADT before doing this.*

Comment: I've tried the zip method (and uninstalled before), and it didn't work. I have no idea what's wrong...

Comment: well.. I can see the AVD manager + the Android SDK manager in the windows menu of eclipse. and in the preferences I can also see the newer targets added.

Comment: ok, i've done it again, and for some reason, now it works fine. I have no idea what happened. sorry. here, take my vote.

Comment: I still cannot see in the AVD manger the API 20 though.
You might find that "annotations.jar" is missing from the $SDKPATH/tools/support in the java build path. I have a copy of Android Studio which has "annotations.jar" . I have just tested it . it works.

Comment: That's odd. Now that I want to export my app, I cannot see Proguard anywhere. I've tried to uninstall the various SDK tools packages, and re-install them, and I can't see it... Has anything changed in this regard?

Comment: Well I don't use Progaurd. I always publish without progaurd because I want to be able receive crash reports easily.

Comment: you can get crash reports if you keep the original code of the published app and the "mapping.txt" file. It takes a few steps, but it works. Anyway, it seems some files are missing, and that people already talked about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471551/adt-v23-sdk-23-android-l-missing-proguard?noredirect=1#comment37874962_24471551 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437564/update-eclipse-with-android-development-tools-23/24456942#24456942

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, finally I had to download a new ADT from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html is faster than trying to fight vs dependencies or adt versions.

Comment: i have done every thing & it's working fine, but when i create a new project my src folder will be empty.

Comment: But again downloading and deleting existing sdk and adt is not the solution, there must be internal bug that is need to be fixed to accept update within existing eclipse

Comment: Yes, they have to fix the bug. Is true that they added Juno instead ADT, @GaRRaPeTa when I open the program I have to select the Java mode view for see the "android interface".

Comment: I've ended up downloading eclipse (luna) and adding the plugin. Seems to work so far.

Comment: This update is containing lots of bugs that are really very time consuming to fix it up and have to search and download other missing parts to make it workable perfectly.