# Where to find FindBugs Eclipse plugin compatible with Java 1.6

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, findbugs

I am not able to upgrade Java to 1.7 but would like to make use of FindBugs plugin for Eclipse (the latest version 3 requires Java 1.7). There doesn't seem to be an old version of the plugin available, anyone any idea where I could obtain it from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [FindBugs Download site on SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=96405), which has all versions available.

You would need version 2.0.3 of the Eclipse Plugin, which is here:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/findbugs/files/findbugs%20eclipse%20plugin/2.0.3/

Comment: This doesn't work. Can't install 2.0.3 using the above URL.

Comment: But it works! I just checked again. Mind that this is for download and local installation, it is not an "Eclipse update site".

Comment: How did you installed? I just extracted in the plugins directory and nothing shows up. I also tried extracting in dropins directory and again nothing showed up.

Comment: [How to install plugin for Eclipse from .zip](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5482554/1005481)