# How to add Redmine and Jenkins as a task-repository to Mylyn in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, jenkins, eclipse-plugin, redmine, mylyn

I'd like to use Mylyn for organizing my tasks and associated 'task contexts' in eclipse. I found on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mylyn) that integrating Jenkins and Redmine is possible.

When I try to add a new repository, no connectors are shown,
[image]

although I already installed a connector for Jenkins:

[image]

In the **Add Task Repository**-list, there is also no entry for Redmine.

So, how can I use Redmine and Jenkins repositories in Mylyn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need the [Redmine Mylyn Connector](https://github.com/ljader/redmine-mylyn-plugin) plugin for redmine . And you also will need to look at [this guide](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Mylyn).

Note that the only way to make it connect correctly for me was to use the connector plugin I linked above and enabling the API secret key(you can enable it from your user account page)on the redmine instance .

Comment: I'm a bit confused right now. In the guide it is mentioned that I (only) need the mylyn-plugin for redmine. I thought I also need a connector plugin for Eclipse. There is also tons of source for different plugins mentioned,... . I also tried the `generic web repository connector` that is mentioned in the guide. I thought it might give similar results, but the only thing it does, is showing everything in a browser-window within eclipse and it limits the number of tasks to 25 - So, am I using it wrong, or does the generic web-connector have such a limited range of function?

Comment: Just use the Eclipse Redmine plugin from sourceforge and enable the API secret key for your user account . Take a look at this guide : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482554/how-to-install-plugin-for-eclipse-from-zip/16074606#16074606 to understand how to manually install a plugin on Eclipse .

Comment: Now everything is installed, I can't set up a query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26064144/generating-a-query-fails-for-integration-of-redmine-and-mylyn-in-eclipse