# Generating a query fails for integration of Redmine and Mylyn in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, redmine, redmine-plugins, mylyn, server-error

I installed the [Redmine-Mylyn-Connector](http://redmin-mylyncon.sourceforge.net/update-site/N/) in Eclipse and had our admin install the [Mylyn-Plugin for Redmine](http://danmunn.github.io/redmine_mylyn_connector/). The connection to Server seems to work:

[image]

When I try to add a query, I receive a `Server Error:`. Unfortunately no more details are available.

[image]

What are potential reasons for this error, and how can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

There might be useful details in the Error Log. Open the Error Log view (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> then <kbd>L</kbd>, or use **Window** > **Show View...**). I would clear the log first (using the red X button in its toolbar), then reproduce the error. You should see error details in the Error Log which might point you to the source of the problem.

Comment: There is no more information available in the errolog: `An exception stack trace is not available.`