# Eclipse Android plugin issue "Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/AppTheme')"

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am using Eclipse Android plugins to build a project, but I am getting this error when create a new project. And also in generated project hierarchy src files and layout files doesnt exist. I tried to add support libraries but nothing changed.

How do I fix it?

Comment: Change `@style/AppTheme` to a valid value...

Comment: I added support/v7/appcompat. After adding library the error has gone but now I can't add new activity :/ Still searching solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the bug in the adt plugin, Download the patch from http://tools.android.com/download/adt-issue-82393-v4.zip?attredirects=0&d=1 and install the adt plugin manually from .zip file (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82393).

For Manual Installation please follow [How to install plugin for Eclipse from .zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482554/how-to-install-plugin-for-eclipse-from-zip)

Answer (score 0):

happened to me too.
to solve it i just get into res-->vaules and changed it to look like that:

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    </style>

</resources>
```

hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

after importing support/v7/appcompat
1-try to reference AppCompat in your android project.
,Right click on your android project. Goto Properties. goto andorid. Click Add Library and reference the same.
2- go to project then clean and Rebuild your project
if that didn't work you gotta check your style tags and try to replace them

Comment: After I add support/v7/appcompat library the error has gone but I can't add new activity or someting else

Comment: if you can't add new activity try to update the Eclipse plugin: Eclipse --> Help --> Install new software --> Pasted URL http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ pressed Enter. After updating the plugin

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the bug in the adt plugin, you have configured de app_compact_v7 to use api level >= 21 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OBfTbZwTrKk
or use Android Studio and fix the problem...