# unable to configure maven in to eclipse (jundo)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

i want to install maven plug in on eclipse. but when add the maven site in install software section, and beginning to download and install it, but in preference maven option does not show . how can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this using windows?
If Ubuntu, a simple sudo apt-get install maven command would do.

If windows, try the drop in method for plugin installation as seen on this link [How to install plugin for Eclipse from .zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482554/how-to-install-plugin-for-eclipse-from-zip)

Comment: Yes i am using windows 7