# Unable to add SoapUI plugin in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, soapui, eclipse-marketplace

Need to install SoapUI plugin into Eclipse(MARS)..
tried Help->Install New S/W-> SoapUI-***http://www.soapui.org/eclipse/update/site.xml*** link....but unable to find the plugin ...tried few other links too but the plugin could not be found

No proper solution available when googled.Pls help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SoapUI Eclipse plugin is deprecated.
SoapUI has removed eclipse plugin from update sites i.e why you are getting unable to find the plugin. 
You can get the Eclipse plugin from archive:

```
http://sourceforge.net/projects/soapui/files/soapui-eclipse-plugin/4.0.1/
```

download Eclipse plugin from here. and Install this in eclipse using Archive.

This will be soapUI 4.0.1, I recommend to use latest SoapUI

Comment: Not deprecated, **abandoned**!

Comment: SoapUI eclipse plugin is no more available

Answer (score 1):

To perform the installation, you should not look in the repos. Eclipse is available for installation as a file [here](https://www.soapui.org/downloads/soapui/soapui-os-older-versions.html#soapui-eclipse-plugin).

Comment: would be better to sum up what the main points of the link...

Answer (score -1):

As of 2018-01-15, the SOAP UI eclipse plugin doesn't exist on their site and update site. However, you can still download the plugin [here](https://www.soapui.org/downloads/soapui/soapui-os-older-versions.html#soapui-eclipse-plugin). This leads to the archived older versions of plugins, where you can download the latest version of the plugin (4.0.1 as of this date). Then, you can use the following [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16074606/7033626) to install the zip file into eclipse. It may take some time, but it works. I am using the latest Eclipse without problems with this plugin.