# Unable to find Randoop eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, eclipse-plugin, randoop

My requirement is to generate test cases automatically in JAVA, for which i was considering to use Randoop. Is there any `url`for downloading `Randoop` plugin for `eclipse`. I can't access eclipse market-place from my network. I tried downloading eclipse-plugin from [github](https://github.com/randoop/randoop-eclipse-plugin) , but `Randoop` jar file is not present on it. How can I install this plugin ?

Comment: is this issue resolved ?

Answer (score 0):

As you say, that link points to the source code.. Unfortunately I couldnt find link to the built jar file, in which case you would need to build it with Apache Ant.  There is also a dependency:

plume.jar - (I think this is the source code for it.. https://github.com/mernst/plume-lib if so you'd need to build this into a jar first too!)

Once built and you have the jar, you can install it as described here: [How to install plugin for Eclipse from .zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482554/how-to-install-plugin-for-eclipse-from-zip)

Answer (score 0):

Since the Eclipse plugin is not currently supported from within Randoop,
the only option to run Randoop from within Eclipse is as a [stand-alone external tool](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-97_standalone_ets.htm?cp=0_1_2_2_1).

Answer (score 0):

If someone is interested in the old version of the eclipse plugin for randoop, I was able to set up an update site here: https://cs.unibg.it/gargantini/didattica/swtestandver/radoopeclipse.updateSite/
It uses an old version of randoop, we may work in the future to update the plugin with the new randoop.