# How to install an older Eclipse plugin of SonarLint

Tags: eclipse, sonarlint, sonarlint-eclipse

Currently in the Eclipse Marketplace SonarLint is only available in the latest version (2.5.1). For a compatibility reason I need to have version (2.2.1).

How can i install an older version of my choice?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Instead of using Eclipse Marketplace, use menu in **Help → Install New Software.**
Add sonarlint URL:

```
http://eclipse.sonarlint.org/
```

and than *uncheck* "Show only the latest versions of available software".

You will see all available version of sonarlint. If you already have it installed with unexpected version, you need to uninstall it first in Help → Installation Details.

Comment: Unfortunately, it appears that they're only making the most recent versions available at all this way. As of August 2017, when I uncheck "Show only the latest versions..." I see only 3.2.0.x and 3.1.0.x. I'm trying to local 2.2.1 due to limitations on the SonarQube server side, so I'm still digging.

Answer (score 9):

The official zip files for legacy versions of SonarLint are here:

https://binaries.sonarsource.com/SonarLint-for-Eclipse/releases/

After downloading the zip file, in Eclipse:

```
Help -> Install New Software -> Add -> Archive -> the zip file
```

**Edit**: as pointed by user1323562 in comments the new URL is:

https://binaries.sonarsource.com/?prefix=SonarLint-for-Eclipse/releases/

Comment: URL now is > https://binaries.sonarsource.com/?prefix=SonarLint-for-Eclipse/releases/

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you

Answer (score 7):

I had exactly the same issue. Here is how I managed it:

1. Ask Google for "sonarlint 2.1.0"
2. You'll find a page link to [2.1.0 - Bintray](https://bintray.com/sonarsource/SonarLint-for-Eclipse/releases/2.1.0)
3. You will be able to download a zip.
4. Then, this [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482554/how-to-install-plugin-for-eclipse-from-zip) will help you install the zip from your disk.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot man. I was searching for the zip file for a long time and you saved my day! \O/

Answer (score 1):

The new URL to install older Sonarlint versions is

https://eclipse-uc.sonarlint.org with this one you can install the older versions from 5.9 up to 7.6