# Unable to Finish connecting to SonarQube server

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, sonarlint

This is going to sound like a ridiculous question, but using the SonarLint Eclipse plugin (v3.2.0) on the latest Eclipse (Oxygen), I am unable to add a new SonarQube server connection.

I am working behind a company firewall, but that doesnt appear to be an issue. I am following the steps [here](http://www.sonarlint.org/eclipse/index.html) and am able to successfully connect to our internal SonarQube instance, provide my credentials, but it is just on the final step, that the 'Finish' button does not seem to do anything, see screen below:

[image]

I appreciate there is probably some background processes need to run in order for this Finish to actually finish :) But this doesnt appear to be doing anything...Anyone else experience this issue?

Any before people ask, I've restarted Eclipse/laptop, uninstalled and reinstalled SonarLint plugin etc.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Same problem here, trying to connect to our on-premise sonarqube server at the company. Running Eclipse in a archlinux guest on a Windows 7 virtualbox host. Works for a colleague of mine with the same eclipse version.

Comment: Does the workaround in the current answer work?

Comment: That didnt resolve my issue on my Mac, I dont seem to have any entries for org.sonarlint.eclipse.core. However I tried installing the plugin on my Windows machine and it worked fine straight away. Could it be that the plugin isnt fully supported in Eclipse for Mac?

Answer (score 30):

SonarLint in Eclipse are storing credentials in Eclipse secure storage that itself is protected by a master password. So you must reset it or delete it to add a new SonarQube server connection. You can try this step :

1. In your Eclipse Go to **Window > Preferences**, filter and find *Secure  Storage*.
2. In the Tab **Contents** find and highlight *org.sonarlint.eclipse.core*, click **Delete > Apply > OK**. After deletion process is finished, Eclipse will ask if you want to restart the IDE. It is strongly recommended that you restart the IDE and try again to adding SonarQube server in Eclipse.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

On my linux machine I had the same issue, because the used master password provider doesn't work properly.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45658575) worked for me:

1. Open **Window** > **Preferences**
2. Go to **General** > **Security** > **Secure Storage**
3. At **Master password providers** uncheck the used provider. The enabled provider with the highest priority is the used one [for me it was "*Linux Integration (64 bit)*"].
4. Click **apply**

Comment: This one worked for me. The first answer didn't because I don't have "org.sonarlint.eclipse.core" in secure storage...

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered this problem, but was able to work around it.

This is environment in which I was running:

- Eclipse Oxygen.1
- Linux VM (VirtualBox) on Windows host

Solution that worked for me based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43463465/8921124):

1. Uninstall SonarLint.
2. Reinstall using Help -> Install new software...
3. On the Install dialog, un-check the option "Show only the latest versions of available software"
4. Select the older version of SonarLint.
5. Select Next and continue with the install.
6. After installing, configure your SonarQube server like normal.
7. Upgrade to the latest version of SonarLint via Help -> Check for Updates

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem also concerned the credentials storage but was caused by the Avecto Defendpoint Client. The company restricted the permissions to create subfolders in user home (c:\users<username>). I had to create manually missing subfolders (.sonarlint and .eclipse) after access level elevation and after filling the reason in a text field. Then I had to give the permissions to those folders for myself. Having created them I could proceed with adding server to sonarlint plugin.