# Eclipse Plugins Fail to Update

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Eclipse: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)

Help -> Check for Updates

There are three available updates

Git Integration for Eclipse
Git Integration for Eclipse - Task focused interface
Java implementation of Git

I go through the steps and the update starts, however i get an error. Please see attached screenshot.[image: Failed to Update]

How do i fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install it several ways:

via help-> install software: with this link ([recomended](http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates))

if this doesn't work, I usually do it to the "Macho man way":

- 1)  Download the zip from [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/egit/updates/org.eclipse.egit.repository-4.7.0.201704051617-r.zip)
- 2) Unzip in somewhere well known to you
- 3) Go to the folder "dropins" in your eclipse folder
- 4) past there everything of the plugins folder from the unziped files
- 5) Don't forget reboot ecipse

For more details read [this](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/download/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482554/how-to-install-plugin-for-eclipse-from-zip)

Comment: I'd buy you a beer but since i can't. Take some contribution points instead. :) btw, any ideas why it fails to find the repo?

Comment: I updated the answer including more details, there is a very good answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482554/how-to-install-plugin-for-eclipse-from-zip) also

Comment: Answering you other question, I had recently the same issue with apache Tomcat, and sooooooometimes it found the site, and sooooometimes it doesn't... and well, one day I had no time with trying, so I download the zip and did it that way