# Eclipse manual / offline JBoss Tools Luna install: Missing requirement abc requires 'bundle xyz' but it could not be found

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-luna, ibm-rad, jboss-tools

We have a VM running for development, but on these machines we **absolutely have no Internet connection**. Local machine has Internet access, but no Eclipse there (it's the company's policy, they have to be very strict).

Luna version is 4.4 (essentially it's IBM RAD 9.5 dev tools *sigh*, but this shouldn't matter for my question hopefully). The latest stable for Luna is JBoss Tools 4.2.3 here: https://tools.jboss.org/downloads/jbosstools/luna/4.2.3.Final.html

I finally downloaded a file called (don't remember where)

jbosstools-4.2.3.Final_2015-03-26_22-41-56-B370-updatesite-core.zip

which includes two subdirs `plugins` and `features` and the two required files `artifacts.jar` and `content.jar` ([How to install plugin for Eclipse from .zip](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5482554/396732)). I then went to Eclipse Help -> Install new software -> Add... -> Archive... and selected the file I downloaded (you can copy the files from the local machine to the VM via Ctrl+C and Ctrl-V, but Internet access is forbidden).

The manual installation fails. I only selected a small subset of the features to get the JSF editor:

- JBoss Tools JSF
- JBoss Tools Visual Page Editor

After a very long time after completing some lengthy 15 calculation steps ("Could not perform operation... step x/15, this may take a while." the dialog says:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: JBoss Tools JSF 3.6.2.Final-v20150325-0431-B95 (org.jboss.tools.jsf.feature.feature.group 3.6.2.Final-v20150325-0431-B95)
  **Missing requirement: JBoss Tools Common Core 3.6.2.Final-v20150325-0456-B99 (org.jboss.tools.common.core 3.6.2.Final-v20150325-0456-B99) requires 'bundle org.apache.commons.httpclient 3.1.0' but it could not be found**
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: JBoss Tools Common 3.6.2.Final-v20150325-0456-B99 (org.jboss.tools.common 3.6.2.Final-v20150325-0456-B99)
    To: bundle org.jboss.tools.common.core 3.4.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: El Plug-in 3.6.2.Final-v20150325-0456-B99 (org.jboss.tools.common.el.core 3.6.2.Final-v20150325-0456-B99)
    To: bundle org.jboss.tools.common 0.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: JBoss Tools Common 3.6.2.Final-v20150325-0456-B99 (org.jboss.tools.common.feature.feature.group 3.6.2.Final-v20150325-0456-B99)
    To: org.jboss.tools.common.el.core [3.6.2.Final-v20150325-0456-B99]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: JBoss Tools JSF 3.6.2.Final-v20150325-0431-B95 (org.jboss.tools.jsf.feature.feature.group 3.6.2.Final-v20150325-0431-B95)
    To: org.jboss.tools.common.feature.feature.group 3.6.0
```

I am currently stuck trying to install the required archive(s) **Apache commons-httpclient-3.1.0 manually** to Eclipse (not to the project), because I don't know where to find a ZIP file that contains the commons-httpclient 3.1.0 Eclipse updatesite files.

**Question/s:**

How/where do I get the ZIP files for manual install in Eclipse (updatesite files)? **Does anyone know the URL?**

I need to download the file to my local machine, copy the to the VM via the RDC and install offline there.

The general question would be **where to find any dependencies' Eclipse updatesite files**. I believe commons-httpclient won't stay my only problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a target platform zip you can use, which includes Luna.2 and various compatible bits from Eclipse Orbit:

http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/static/targetplatforms/jbosstoolstarget/4.42.0.Final/jbosstoolstarget-4.42.0.Final.zip

Or, use the equivalent Red Hat JBoss Developer Studio install and its matching target platform zip from here:

http://tools.jboss.org/downloads/devstudio/luna/8.1.0.GA.html#zips

Hope that helps!