# How to make Team Explorer Everywhere (DevOps TFS Plugin for Eclipse) work?

Tags: eclipse, tfs

I am proficient at coding, but always struggling to install stuff, such as maven, plugings etc.
As I am used to version control with DevOps and now want to use Eclipse for a Java project, I try to make DevOps communicate with Eclipse. I have just downloaded Eclipse on this pc.

Unfortunately, installing the plugin of 'Team Explorer Everywhere' won't work. Probably a stupid mistake from my side.

I have been following [this guide](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/eclipse/#:%7E:text=Azure%20DevOps%20services%20works%20with,developers%20to%20use%20Azure%20DevOps.) and also tried [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/hh301122(v=vs.120)).

After adding the location http://dl.microsoft.com/eclipse/tfs, I get the error that it 'Could not find [http://dl.microsoft.com/eclipse/tfs'](http://dl.microsoft.com/eclipse/tfs%27) and the question whether I want to alter the location. I also tried without /tfs.

After some research I found out that I probably need to download something of the plugin first (and then do it manually instead), so I downloaded Source code.zip from [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/releases).
Unfortunately, this does not contain the required folders which are mentioned in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482554/how-to-install-plugin-for-eclipse-from-zip).

Anyone here who can help me out on this?

Comment: From the [release page](https://github.com/microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/releases/tag/14.137.0), download the `TFSEclipsePlugin-UpdateSiteArchive-14.137.0.zip` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may download it from the releases page: https://github.com/microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/releases.

Then in Eclipse add go to `Install New Software`:
[image]

Add location of downloaded archive:

[image]

Then you may select the components:

[image]

After restart, you may select Team Explorer View

[image]

[image]